# What is the time and space complexity of SLSQP minimize algorithm in Scipy?

Tags: python, scipy, mathematical-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I mean [the following method](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.minimize-slsqp.html): `scipy.optimize.minimize(method=’SLSQP’)`

I heard [in this issue](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/3605) that the "The memory required by COBYLA and SLSQP is quadratic in the number of variables. These algorithms are not suitable for solving such large problems.":

Anyone know the exact time&space complexity of this algorithm?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it looks like the memory complexity is O(n^2), where n is the problem dimension (number of variables). This is due to the B-matrix (approximation of the Hessian matrix), as SLSQP is a quasi-Newton method.

About time complexity, I also found [this related issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47497552/scipy-optimize-minimizeslsqp-too-slow-when-given-2000-dim-variable) suggesting the time complexity of O(n^3). But I am not convinced. From what I found the SciPy implementation is a wrapper of old FORTRAN code and the given reference for this is:

*Kraft, D. A software package for sequential quadratic programming. (Wiss. Berichtswesen d. DFVLR, 1988).*

One computational drawback would come from [LDL decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition#LDL_decomposition_2), but only rank-one updates of a LDL decomposition are needed, which can be achieved in O(n^2).

The O(n^3) may still come from the algorithm used to solve the quadratic subproblem. I am still reading the references so I may edit my response here.